Scroll through a div (Swiper)
I'm making this website with a full screen carousel using Swiper.js.
The main carousel is horizontal, but on some slides there's a nested vertical carousel. though I'm having a slight problem with the navigation of both.
The main horizontal carousel works with mouse click control: there're two translucent divs .button-prev and .button-next that are 30% width on each side which transform the cursor into an arrow on hover. So if you click within the right div you go right, and so on for left.
Concerning the vertical carousel, it works on mouse scroll. If you scroll up or down, it navigates vertically.
The problem is if the mouse is on top of one of the navigation divs of the main horizontal carousel, it's not possible to scroll, and so if you want to interact with the vertical nested carousel you need to put your mouse in the middle of the page.
I was wondering if it is possible to scroll through the horizontal carousel navigation divs (as if it was a pointer-event: none), or maybe if I should do the code differently for it to work properly. Do you have any recommendations?


var carouselHorizontal = new Swiper(".carouselHorizontal", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 50,
  loop: true,
  effect: "fade",
  speed: 200,
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".button-next",
    prevEl: ".button-prev",
  },
});

var carouselVertical = new Swiper(".carouselVertical", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  direction: "vertical",
  spaceBetween: 0,
  mousewheel: true,
  speed: 400,
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
});
.button-prev {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  cursor: w-resize;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-next {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  cursor: e-resize;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="swiper carouselHorizontal project">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="projetTitre">TITLE</div>
      <div class="swiper carouselVertical">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="projetTitre">TILE2</div>
      <div class="swiper carouselVertical">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="button-next"></div>
  <div class="button-prev"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>



